# Right way to use static bool

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am using AudioPlayer in Flutter to play different audios that get streamed from Firebase using StreamBuilder. While I am able to stop a certain audio when another one plays by making the AudioPlayer static, I am unable to do the same with play button. When a certain song plays, the play button remains in "play" state even when the song changes.

Here is the snipped of my code

```
class _RingtoneWidgetState extends State<RingtoneWidget> {
  static AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

  AuthenticationScreenController authenticationScreenController =
      Get.put(AuthenticationScreenController());

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    audioPlayer.stop().whenComplete(() {
      widget.isPlaying = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      .....
            title: CustomText(widget.ringtoneTitle as String, 18,
                FontWeight.w500, AppColors.whiteColor),
            subtitle: CustomText(
                "x audio usado: ${widget.numberOfTimesRingtoneUsed}",
                12,
                FontWeight.w400,
                AppColors.whiteColor),
            trailing: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                widget.isPlaying
                    ? await audioPlayer.stop().whenComplete(() {
                        setState(() {
                          widget.isPlaying = !widget.isPlaying;
                        });
                      })
                    : await audioPlayer
                        .play(UrlSource(widget.audioUrl as String))
                        .whenComplete(() {
                        setState(() {
                          widget.isPlaying = !widget.isPlaying;
                        });
                      });
              },
              child: widget.isPlaying
                  ? const Icon(
                      Icons.pause_circle,
                      color: AppColors.whiteColor,
                    )
                  : const Icon(
                      Icons.play_circle_outlined,
                      color: AppColors.whiteColor,
                    ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code for screen where this widget is listed

```
Expanded(
                    child: Scaffold(
                      backgroundColor: AppColors.defaultColor,
                      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('artistdata')
                            .doc(authInstance.currentUser!.email)
                            .collection('songs')
                            .snapshots(),
                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.waiting) {
                            return Text("Loading");
                          }
                          FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection('artistdata')
                              .doc(authInstance.currentUser!.email)
                              .collection('songs')
                              .get()
                              .then(
                            (value) {
                              authenticationScreenController
                                  .totalNumberOfSongs.value = value.size;
                            },
                          );
                          return ListView(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
                            children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                              Map<String, dynamic> data =
                                  document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                              return RingtoneWidget(
                                false,
                                audioUrl: data['audiourl'],
                                imageUrl: data['imageurl'],
                                numberOfTimesRingtoneUsed:
                                    data['numberoftimesused'],
                                ringtoneTitle: data['songtitle'],
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```